# How can to come back to my view when I confirm form?

Tags: ios, xcode, popup, reloaddata

I’m I downloaded MZFormSheetController library for my app.

I’ve got a problem on my popup. When I am on my TableViewController, I tap on a row to get popup to open up so that I can change the name. The popup opens, I set the name and when I tap on the button to correct the name, I call the button method but i can’t close my popup while reload my list.

```
- (IBAction)modifierTournoi:(id)sender {
     //code to update database

     //this method close the popup but don't call method viewWillAppear to reload database
     //I don't know what method i can use..?
     [self dismissFormSheetControllerAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(MZFormSheetController *formSheetController) {
     }];
}
```

Before that, I used the method popViewControllerAnimated to come back to my list while recharging my list.

```
- (IBAction)modifierJoueur:(id)sender {
    //code to update database
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
}
```

Can you help me please ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Providing some code you've written will greatly help people to understand you problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a specific completion handler for this purpose built into the library you are using:

```
- (IBAction)modifierTournoi:(id)sender {
     //code to update database

     //this method close the popup but don't call method viewWillAppear to reload database
     //I don't know what method i can use..?
     [self dismissFormSheetControllerAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(MZFormSheetController *formSheetController) {

            // Reloading your database should work in here.
     }];
}
```

The reason viewWillAppear will not be being called is because rather than placing a viewController modally above your window, I imagine MZFormSheetController will be adding a UIView above all presented UIViews, so viewWillAppear will never be called. But as I said above, you should be able to reload in the completion handler block.

Comment: Ok, I reload data in the completion handler block. I send my TableView and my NSMutableArray to reload data in my segue.

But my table list don't reload it...

[self dismissFormSheetControllerAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(MZFormSheetController *formSheetController) {
        self.listeTournois = [TournoiBdd getAllTournois];
        [self.tournoiTableView reloadData];
    }];

Comment: Probably going to need more code implementation if I'm going to help from here on. Have you tried breakpointing to see if tableView methods such as tableView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: are being called after you call reloadData? Or maybe even just stick a break point in the completion block to make sure that is being called!

Comment: Oh Thanks, I forgot to add breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I just call the method to reload my array at the beginning of cellForRowAtIndexPath method and it's work !!!

Thank you so much simonthumper !